# Replace elements in factor levels

Tags: r

The problem is rather straight forward. For some reason, I can't think of a simple solution, not could I find one online. Let's assume this is my data, where the variable is a factor:

```
Time
8:10
8:15
8:30
8:45
10:10
10:15
10:45
```

I want to convert all the levels at 10 to 8, where the outcome looks like this:

```
Time
8:10
8:15
8:30
8:45
8:10
8:15
8:45
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Here is one way: `Time <- factor(sub("^10", "8", Time))`. Note that this will drop the previous levels that started with `10`.

Comment: I should add a `:` to replace the hour not the minutes, right? Just double-checking.

Comment: No, try it as is. Also, if you do not want to drop the levels I've mentioned in my first comment, use just `sub(.)`, don't wrap `factor` around it.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response and the extra feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Rui Barradas suggested, you can do this:

```
Time <- as.factor(c(
"8:10",
"8:15",
"8:30",
"8:45",
"10:10",
"10:15",
"10:45"
))

factor(sub("^10", "8", Time))
[1] 8:10 8:15 8:30 8:45 8:10 8:15 8:45
Levels: 8:10 8:15 8:30 8:45
```

To answer your question: "I should add a : to replace the hour not the minutes, right?" – No, you don't need to do this. The '^' in the sub argument means start of the string in regex. So this will only select hours.

If we need to scale this up for a large dataset, we can take the advice from @lmo and take a more direct approach; see:

```
levels(Time) <- sub("^10", "8", Time)
```

Time comparison:

```
require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(factor(sub("^10", "8", Time)),
               levels(Time) <- sub("^10", "8", Time))

Unit: microseconds
                                 expr    min      lq     mean  median
        factor(sub("^10", "8", Time)) 56.254 57.9945 77.58347 58.6855
levels(Time) <- sub("^10", "8", Time) 27.932 28.9770 32.59209 30.4035
```

Comment: You can also do this directly with the factor levels: `levels(Time) <- sub("^10", "8", Time)`. In this instance, it won't matter in terms of efficiency, but if the vector is large and there are many repeated values, I am pretty sure that operating on the levels will be significantly faster. It is also possible that the regex functions are smart enough to do this automatically.